# I use sanitize html for xss attacks,if i want to use Markdown.js

Tags: node.js, express, markdown, sanitize

I use Markdown.js and i use sanitize-html for xss attacks.

I read most articles about xss attack (if want to use markdown.js) like this [markdown securely](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-do-i-use-markdown-securely/14674#14674) and one more [markdown-xss-testing](https://discuss.flarum.org/d/489-testing-markdown-xss).

Please look at my codes,this is enough or not(for xss attack).

This is my `server.js`:

```js
var comment=req.body.comment;
var z=markdown.toHTML(comment);
   var clean = sanitizeHtml(z, {
  allowedTags: ['b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a','h1','img','blockquote'],
  allowedAttributes: {'a': [ 'href' ],'img':['src']},
  
  allowedIframeHostnames: []
})
console.log(clean)
```

And i tried some codes(values are req.body.comment) for xss attacks, like here:

```
[Example](javascript://\nalert%28%22xss%22%29)//req.body.comment  
{@onclick=alert('hi')}some paragraph          //req.body.comment
[test](javascript://%0d%0aprompt(1))          //req.body.comment
```

Outputs here console.log(clean):

```
<a>Example</a>  
{@onclick=alert('hi')}some paragraph //not clickable
<a>test</a>
```

I have tried many other code and always avoided attacks.

Comment: I do not know English very well, I could not explain my question very well.So soryy.

Comment: For reference, I've asked a similar question about `DOMPurify` and `markdown-it` that may be of help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741262/how-to-install-import-and-use-dompurify-in-frontend-js-file