# How to install, import and use DOMPurify in frontend js file?

Tags: javascript, sanitization, dompurify

This is more of a "can you please confirm this is correct" type of question, as I think I resolved it in the process of writing the question but hopefully it will be of help to other people who are a bit hesitant when it comes to implementing [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify).

**Short Version**

Is it safe/valid to import and use `DOMPurify` like this in frontend js file:

```
npm install dompurify --save

import DOMPurify from 'dompurify'; 

var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize('<img src=x onerror=alert(1)//>', {SAFE_FOR_JQUERY: true});
```

**Detailed Version**

Currently my main frontend js file imports using these conventions:

```
import ClipboardJS from 'clipboard';

// date-fns functions
import getYear from 'date-fns/get_year';
import getMonth from 'date-fns/get_month';
import getDaysInMonth from 'date-fns/get_days_in_month';
import startOfMonth from 'date-fns/start_of_month';
import getDay from 'date-fns/get_day';
import format from 'date-fns/format';

import Cookies from './js.cookie';
```

I tried the following:

```
npm install dompurify --save

import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

console.log(DOMPurify.sanitize('<img src=x onerror=alert(1)//>', {SAFE_FOR_JQUERY: true}));
console.log(DOMPurify.sanitize('<svg><g/onload=alert(2)//<p>', {SAFE_FOR_JQUERY: true}));
console.log(DOMPurify.sanitize('<p>abc<iframe/\/src=jAva&Tab;script:alert(3)>def', {SAFE_FOR_JQUERY: true}));
console.log(DOMPurify.sanitize('<math><mi//xlink:href="data:x,<script>alert(4)</script>">', {SAFE_FOR_JQUERY: true})); 
console.log(DOMPurify.sanitize('<TABLE><tr><td>HELLO</tr></TABL>', {SAFE_FOR_JQUERY: true}));
console.log(DOMPurify.sanitize('<UL><li><A HREF=//google.com>click</UL>', {SAFE_FOR_JQUERY: true}));
```

The string examples are from here:

https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify#some-purification-samples-please

And use the `SAFE_FOR_JQUERY` flag mentioned here:

https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify#can-i-configure-it

Everything is logging as expected, ie:

```
<img src="x">
<svg><g></g></svg>
<p>abcdef</p>
<math><mi></mi></math>
<table><tbody><tr><td>HELLO</td></tr></tbody></table>
<ul><li><a href="//google.com">click</a></li></ul>
```

So that is good.

**Question**

The [official DOMPurify readme](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) shows the following ways to import and use:

```
// method 01
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/purify.min.js"></script>
var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty);

// method 02
require(['dompurify'], function(DOMPurify) {
    var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty);
});

// method 03
npm install dompurify
const createDOMPurify = require('dompurify');
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const window = (new JSDOM('')).window;
const DOMPurify = createDOMPurify(window);

const clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty);

// method 04
const createDOMPurify = require('dompurify');
const jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

const window = jsdom('').defaultView;
const DOMPurify = createDOMPurify(window);

const clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty);
```

Even though the way I have implemented it is not listed, is this still a safe/valid way to do it:

```
npm install dompurify --save

import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
```

**PS, if required for context...**

The implementation scenario is:

`01)`  A user starts with a span:

```
<span class="editable" data-previous_value="here is previously saved value">here is previously saved value</span>
```

`02)`  When the span is clicked on, the value of `data-previous_value` is added to an `input` element which replaces the `span`.

`03)`  A user modifies the text in the `input` element and clicks save.

`04)`  I use [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) with the `html` option set to `false` and [markdown-it-attrs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-attrs) (to add css styles) and [markdown-it-span](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-span) (to define `spans`) to render any markdown as html (links, images, classes, spans etc).

`05)`  The new value is added to a new `span` element (rendered with `markdown-it`) and `data` attribute (unrendered) which replaces the `input` element.

`06)`  The new, unrendered, value is saved in `MongoDB` database via `Node/Express`.

As an example, the following input:

```
![img](/img/my_thumb.jpg){.video_thumb} [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)
```

is converted to this html:

```
<span class="editable" data-previous_value="![img](/img/my_thumb.jpg){.video_thumb} [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)">
<img src="/img/my_thumb.jpg" alt="img" class="video_thumb"> 
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">Video</a>
</span>
```

I am thinking of sanitizing the input with `DOMPurify` before it gets to `markdown-it` (before step 04).

Answer (score 8):

For React:

```
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(dirtyContent) }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

For React for

```
const SanitizedComponent = (props) => {
  const reactComponentHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    props.children
  );
  const htmlSanatized = DOMPurify.sanitize(reactComponentHtml);
  return <div>{parser(htmlSanatized)}</div>;
};
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-scwhqf?file=App.tsx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).